# Have UINavigationController auto-adapt to how it's presented

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on a view controller that can be presented modally or pushed into a navigation stack. I made it a `UINavigationController` subclass so that I get all the `UIToolbar` stuff for free. I can present it modally using:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Problem is, `UINavigationController` doesn't allow pushing another `UINavigationController` into it (makes sense), so this crashes it:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Would there be a way to detect how `myViewController` is presented and automatically have it switch between `UINavigationController` and `UIViewController` accordingly so that I don't need 2 different classes?

In other words, myViewController would be able to detect how it's getting presented and pushing it would come down to something like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController.topViewController animated:YES];
```

**NOTE**: Something like this would probably do, but it's getting too far away from the default UIViewController behaviors:

```
[myViewController pushIntoNavigationController:navController]; // only push myViewController.topViewController
[myViewController presentModallyInParentController:parentController]; // push the whole myViewController
```

Comment: Just regarding subclassing UINavigationController to "get all the UIToolbar stuff for free": UINavigationController includes a free UIToolbar already, it's hidden by default. Use the `setToolbarHidden:animated:` method on your UINavigationController to unhide it. You'll be able to do everything you need from a regular UIToolbar by accessing it via the UINavigationController's `toolbar` property

Comment: Well that's what I meant, I'm subclassing it so that I can easily add buttons to the already existing toolbar and I don't need to create one myself, add it to the view hierarchy, etc.

Comment: You don't have to subclass to use the `setToolbarItems:` method on `UINavigationController.toolbar` though.

Comment: I know, but the controller in question is [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController), it's a reusable component (it has to be a subclass right off the bat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `myViewController` subclass, create a method something like this:

```
- (void)presentFromViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController
{
    if ([[presentingViewController class] isEqual:[UINavigationController class]])
        [presentingViewController pushViewController:self.topViewController animated:YES];
    else
        [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:self animated:YES];
}
```

Would this work or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: That's a slight improvement over what I wrote at the end of my question. But ideally I'd like it to be completely transparent (still get presented using `pushViewController` and `presentModalViewController` methods).

Comment: Marked this answer as accepted, since it's probably my best option, outside of splitting my VC in 2 different classes (1 NVC for modal view presenting and the regular VC for pushing it).